# Как скрыть диалоговое окно?

Tags: java, android

Имеется `AlertDialog.Builder`, у которого разметка кастомный `.xml`
Есть кнопка в этой разметке по нажатии которой окошко должно исчезнуть. Метод `.dismiss()` не доступен. Как мне убрать диалоговое окно

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_choose_potential, null);
builder.setView(dialogView);
builder.setTitle("...");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Должно как то так получится:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_choose_potential, null);
builder.setView(dialogView);
builder.setTitle("...");
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

Button button = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
  public void onClick (View v){
    dialog.dissmis();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Это конечно идеологически неверно, управлять диалогом не его собственными кнопками, а из кастомного view, но технически возможно.

Как-то так:

```
final AlertDilog alert = builder.build();
Button btn = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(...);
btn.setOnClickListener({ alert.dismiss() });
```

Псевдокод, но надеюсь идея понятна.